# How can I delete from point A to point B - everything that is inside?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have a very long .csv file that I need to rework. I would like to delete everything from point (A) to point (B). All the posts in the CSV file have different SVGs and path IDs. I can't replace them all. I think I would need a little JS to master this.

```
<h2 id="setting-up-a-payment">Setting up a payment<a class="autolink-header" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="#setting-up-a-payment"><span class="visually-hidden"> permalink</span><svg class="autolink-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M9.199 13.599a5.99 5.99 0 0 0 3.949 2.345 5.987 5.987 0 0 0 5.105-1.702l2.995-2.994a5.992 5.992 0 0 0 1.695-4.285 5.976 5.976 0 0 0-1.831-4.211 5.99 5.99 0 0 0-6.431-1.242 6.003 6.003 0 0 0-1.905 1.24l-1.731 1.721a.999.999 0 1 0 1.41 1.418l1.709-1.699a3.985 3.985 0 0 1 2.761-1.123 3.975 3.975 0 0 1 2.799 1.122 3.997 3.997 0 0 1 .111 5.644l-3.005 3.006a3.982 3.982 0 0 1-3.395 1.126 3.987 3.987 0 0 1-2.632-1.563A1 1 0 0 0 9.201 13.6zm5.602-3.198a5.99 5.99 0 0 0-3.949-2.345 5.987 5.987 0 0 0-5.105 1.702l-2.995 2.994a5.992 5.992 0 0 0-1.695 4.285 5.976 5.976 0 0 0 1.831 4.211 5.99 5.99 0 0 0 6.431 1.242 6.003 6.003 0 0 0 1.905-1.24l1.723-1.723a.999.999 0 1 0-1.414-1.414L9.836 19.81a3.985 3.985 0 0 1-2.761 1.123 3.975 3.975 0 0 1-2.799-1.122 3.997 3.997 0 0 1-.111-5.644l3.005-3.006a3.982 3.982 0 0 1 3.395-1.126 3.987 3.987 0 0 1 2.632 1.563 1 1 0 0 0 1.602-1.198z"></path></svg></a></h2>
```

**How it should be ->**

```
<h2>Setting up a payment</h2>
```

Comment: It's not clear how this relates to a CSV file or where points A and B are. It looks like you simply want to empty the heading elements. Is this correct? Please revise to better represent the CSV file (or show the array structure, if that's the case).

Comment: Also, if you're asking for JavaScript, _tag_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "(<a class.+ )(.+)(<\/path.+)"; "$1$3")
```

[image]

Comment: he is not deleting everything inside :/ 
thanks for your help with regexreplace function.

Comment: I have changed the post above.
Below is the article!

I tried , unfortunately it does not work :S